# Ubuntu Emacs 'Invalid read syntax: )' error

Tags: emacs

I'm trying to rebind the backspace key to actually do backwards delete instead of C-h ? in emacs on ubuntu.

In my `.emacs.el` init file i have `(global-set-key [(control ?h)] 'delete-backward-char')`

and on emacs start up i get `Invalid read syntax: )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an extra ' at the end of `delete-backward-char` it should be
`(global-set-key [(control ?h)] 'delete-backward-char)`